# Adding string in html content

Tags: html, ios, swift

I have a html content of url:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
        (data, response, error) in
```

(url!) is url which is loading and:

```
let urlContent = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

So, urlContent is html content of url which is loading.I have a string

```
let string = "Custom string in html content"
```

which i want to add in urlContent, between `<body> </body>` tags

How can i do this?
Thanks

Comment: let me see if I understand, you want to be able to change the HTML code right?

Comment: yes,then this string will be a javascript code.Is it possible?

Comment: yes it is. you can append js to one webview. 5 min I will post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {


    [_WebViewPrograma stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:**(your js here)**];

    [_WebViewPrograma stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunction();"];
}
```

Use this code, if there is anything that you might need, I will try to help